# Script to compile multiple classes with java using jars, but no eclipse

Tags: java, compilation, classpath, javac

I`m trying to compile this project 
[image]

It`s not an easy question, I tried to follow a lot of tutorials but no success.

Comment: HI Andreas, I already tried. I need to know how to compile this without maven, etc. Theres no reason to use a dependency manager. Please, take a look on the lib folder, I use vs code, I know what Im doing, It`s still not easy to me and probably people always use a pk manager or eclipse.

Comment: The Project has a Makefile and a build.sh

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to compile your project the good old fashion way, through the command line.  For that, you will need to run `javac` program.  Looking at your folder structure and concluding the JDK folder is setup in the system path, the command line running from your project folder may look like this:

```
javac -cp ./lib -d ./bin -sourcepath ./src
```

I say "may" because I added the `./bin` folder to your file structure since you need a place to put the generated class files.  Keep in mind I specified your directories in a Linux file format - the forward slash.  You can run `javac -help` for further instructions on how to compile a class/project.

Comment: Thank you Jose, this is the original repo https://github.com/aabarbosa/compiler, but I`m still in doubt, since this is a duplicated question, I don`t know what it is missing.

Comment: It looks like the Makefile in the project is not completely correct, I would ask the author to fix it and/or document the building process.

Comment: Following on @eckes comment, take a look at your Makefile's `CUPJAR` variable - the specified `jar` file path is different from your posting file structure.

Comment: I got to reuse code from a similar project and I'm here to solve and improve the Makefile or prererably replace with a bash script. I think I will forget the Java technology for personal projects by now. I'm not happy with the java community and it seems that they always tell you to use Eclipse. Since I didn't find good material, easy and straightforward of how to define packages to compile easily. I still think it's not a duplicated question, but you may guess it. Another point is that the build.sh is a temporary file I programmed to generate the necessary files for the compiling step.